# Make arbitrary widget appear as a top-level window in GTK on X

Tags: winapi, user-interface, gtk, cross-platform, porting

In Windows, it is possible to say

```
CreateWindow("myclass",...,WS_CHILD,...);
```

or

```
CreateWindow("myclass",...,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,...);
```

It is also possible to switch appearance at will:

```
SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)handle,GWL_STYLE,style_1);
SetWindowPos((HWND)handle,HWND_TOP,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER |   SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)handle,GWL_EXSTYLE,style_0);
SetWindowPos((HWND)handle,HWND_TOP,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
if(style_1&WS_CHILD)
    {
    HWND owner=GetWindow((HWND)handle,GW_OWNER);
    SetParent((HWND)handle,owner);
    }
else
    {SetParent((HWND)handle,NULL);}
```

It seems to me that most other GUI toolkits make a clear distinction between top-level windows and other widgets. The question is if and how it is possible to implement similar behavior in GTK on X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL` and `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP` - unless you know what you do use the first. Also RTM [Standard Enumerations: GTK+ 3 Reference Manual from Wayback Machine (archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140724083618/https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkWindowType)

---

You need to create a `GtkWindow` or `GtkMainWindow` and then add your desired widget `x` via `gtk_container_add` to the window you created.

Comment: But do these apply to GtkButton, GtkToolbar, .... In Windows, I can always say WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW to popout the widget.

From theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial: "One thing to remember about controls is that they are just windows. Like any other window they have a window procedure, a window class etc... that is registered by the system. Anything you can do with a normal window you can do with a control. "

Comment: You can not translate all properties of the WinAPI 1:1 to Gtk+ - that won't work. You need to _understand how_ each toolkit works, then you can start mapping calls. Nevertheless, Gtk+ has a widget tree which are NOT `GtkWindow`s. Actually a `GtkWindow` is derived from a `GtkWidget`.